# Cannot find category for slug:xxxxxx in commercetools

Tags: commercetools

### i am creating new products for commerce tools with the below data, but getting the slug exception.
categories:
key,externalId,name.de,slug.de,name.en,slug.en,name.it,slug.it,parentId,orderHint,webImageUrl,iosImageUrl
c5,5,Collection,collection,Collection,collection,Collection,collection,,0.0005,,
c551,551,The Home of Golf,collection-The-Home-of-Golf,The Home of Golf,collection-The-Home-of-Golf,The Home of Golf,collection-The-Home-of-Golf,5,0.000188,,

products:
productType,variantId,sku            ,prices    ,tax     ,categories     ,images                                                                                 ,name.en         ,description.en,slug.en                       ,metaTitle.en,metaDescription.en,metaKeywords.en,name.de           ,description.de,slug.de                         ,metaTitle.de,metaDescription.de,metaKeywords.de,name.it,description.it,slug.it,metaTitle.it,metaDescription.it,metaKeywords.it,creationDate,articleNumberManufacturer,articleNumberMax,matrixId        ,baseId,designer    ,madeInItaly,completeTheLook,commonSize,size,color,colorFreeDefinition.en,details.en,colorFreeDefinition.de,details.de,colorFreeDefinition.it,details.it,style   ,gender,season,isOnStock,isLook,lookProducts,seasonNew,variantKey
main,1,M0E20000000EEUD,EUR 16875;EUR 11066 b2b;US-USD 16875;USD 11066 b2b;DE-EUR 13500;IT-EUR 13500;GB-EUR 13500;DE-EUR 13095#sunrise-store-berlin;EUR 17719#sunrise-store-vienna;DE-EUR 14445#sunrise-store-munich;DE-EUR 12960#sunrise-store-cologne;DE-EUR 12825#sunrise-store-hamburg;US-USD 13095#sunrise-store-boston-2;USD 17719#sunrise-store-chicago;US-USD 14445#sunrise-store-boston-1;US-USD 12960#sunrise-store-sanfrancisco;US-USD 12825#sunrise-store-newyork,standard,Collection>The Home of Golf,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/commercetools-maximilian/products/081403_1_medium.jpg,T-Shirt Majestic Filatures silver,,majestic-filatures-tshirt-E150904-silver,,,,T-Shirt Majestic Filatures silber,,majestic-filatures-tshirt-E150904-silber,,,,,,,,,,,E15 09 04 644,81403,M0E20000000EEUD,81403,majesticfilatures,no,,xs,0,silver,silver,,silber,,,,sporty,women,s15,,,,,M0E20000000EEUD

,2,M0E20000000EEUE,EUR 16875;EUR 11066 b2b;US-USD 16875;USD 11066 b2b;DE-EUR 13500;IT-EUR 13500;GB-EUR 13500;DE-EUR 13230#sunrise-store-berlin;EUR 15356#sunrise-store-vienna;DE-EUR 13230#sunrise-store-munich;DE-EUR 13905#sunrise-store-cologne;DE-EUR 14445#sunrise-store-hamburg;US-USD 13230#sunrise-store-boston-2;USD 15356#sunrise-store-chicago;US-USD 13230#sunrise-store-boston-1;US-USD 13905#sunrise-store-sanfrancisco;US-USD 14445#sunrise-store-newyork,,,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/commercetools-maximilian/products/081403_1_medium.jpg,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,E15 09 04 644,81403,M0E20000000EEUE,81403,majesticfilatures,no,,s,1,silver,silver,,silber,,,,sporty,women,s15,,,,,M0E20000000EEUE
---------------------error log:
{
"stack": "Error:  collection-the-home-of-golf\n    at /mnt/c/commercetools-data/dist/lib/products.js:74:11\n    at Array.map ()\n    at withCategories (/mnt/c/commercetools-data/dist/lib/products.js:70:77)\n    at /mnt/c/commercetools-data/dist/lib/products.js:241:17\n    at Array.map ()\n    at /mnt/c/commercetools-data/dist/lib/products.js:273:44\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)"
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your request, for this issue you will be better served by creating a support ticket on the commercetools support portal.
https://jira.commercetools.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/1

Please attach a sample product from your import file and the steps you take to import the file.

Best Regards
Brian